# What does the Book with Seven Seals contains?

Tags: revelation

We know what happens when each of the seven seals are broken. But there's no more mention of this book once the seals are broken.

What does this book contain?
Does the Lamb actually read it's content?
What happens to it afterwards, once the seals are broken?

This is difficult to understand.

Comment: What do you see, revealed, when the seals are opened, one by one ? Each opening is followed by an event. The event could not take place until the Lion of the tribe of Judah, personally, opened each seal in turn.

Comment: If the Bible is silent on a particular question, then all you will get are personal opinions.  Please read these articles:   How to ask a good question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
What topics are allowed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several popular modern interpretations given on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_seals

Preterist - fulfillment in the first few centuries following Christ;
Historicist - fulfillment over the centuries, even up to modern times; 
Futurist - Mostly future to the end of the world;
Idealist - Ethical forces rather than historical events are emphasized:

Examples of each interpretation are given.
For the earliest commentary check Victorinus of Pettau (250-303).

http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0712.htm

In this day and age, many people have their own opinions about what the seals mean. I suggest comparing it with the Olivet Discourse (Matt 24-25, Mark 13, Luke 21). Another Interesting comparison is with Jesus' parable of the wheat and tares at the end of the world (Matt 13:24-52). An early Christian text that shared much of the same symbolism with Revelation and Jesus' parables was the Shepherd of Hermas. (100-160)

http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/shepherd-lightfoot.html

Another text that contains some of the same symbolism is the second temple period apocalypse 1 Enoch. (300-200 BC)

http://wesley.nnu.edu/index.php?id=2126

Answer (score 1):

@Allen Fuller's answer is a good summary of what people *think* is contained in the Seven Seals. The key is in the wording: they are called seals. The meaning is sealed up, hidden.

Consider what the angel told Daniel:

> “The vision of the evenings and mornings that has been given you is
>   true, but seal up the vision, for it concerns the distant future.”
>   (Daniel 8:26)

One commentator (Ellis Skolfield) believes that Daniel rearranged the chapters of his book to make the pattern more complicated, to deter others from gaining full understanding until God so wills.

Consider what another angel told John:

> And when the seven thunders spoke, I was about to write; but I heard a
>   voice from heaven say, “Seal up what the seven thunders have said and
>   do not write it down.” (Revelation 10:4)

In this case, John was told to not even write it down.

I believe that the Seven Seals are just that - messages that are not for our eyes. Until it is all over, we won't be told what is in them. At best, their contents will be revealed very close to the end, to guide believers when times are darkest.